# How to use viewmodel block function in other template file?

Tags: magento2

I want to add avatax form in other page. We need to use funtion from the below path. How I can use it?
ClassyLlama\AvaTax\Block\ViewModel\AccountAddExemptionZone

Answer (score 0):

> **You can add overwriting into the layout file in the custom module/theme.**

```
   <referenceBlock name="block.name">
       <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_ModuleName::filename.phtml</argument>
       </action>
       <arguments>
            <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">ClassyLlama\AvaTax\Block\ViewModel\AccountAddExemptionZone</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
```

> **You can also override the file and add your method in your block or existing ViewModel.**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

But I want to use in CMS page not the layout file.

Comment: Please share your code and more information.

Comment: From the below file there is button & when we click on button one form will be open.
vendor\avalara\avatax-magento\view\frontend\templates\certificates\add.phtml

I want exactly this form in other CMS page. but in that file there is once function like <?php echo $block->getViewModel()->isCertificatesAutoValidationDisabled()?> but in my custom phtml file I can't use this function directly. Any idea How I can use it?